# Reinstall USB to Port? (Windows 7)

Tags: windows-7, windows, usb, installation, wireless-mouse

So I pulled out my USB mouse stick before it finished installed and now anytime I put it into that port it tells me that it cannot recognize the USB. If I use a different port then everything goes fine and expected.

How do I reinstall my USB to that port?

Comment: When connected to that port open the device manager and then see the other decices if it is there it will show with yellow mark. Then uninstall it then replug the device.

Comment: You can also see the device driver when connected to working port with device manager under USB hub and then also check if the device driver appear there with non working port qnd uninstall driver from both places if required.

Answer (score 0):

I'm betting you will need to edit the registry to clear out the USB entries for that device. If you can convince the device manager to update the driver like @avirk states above, that is easier.

In regedit (launched as Administrator) you would need to locate the HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Enum\USB table, identify your USB device ending with multiple "&MI_00" and "&MI_01" type names, and delete them. You might need to restart Windows. Windows will then rebuild that list when you insert the USB device again. I had to do this to get my old Canon camcorder working.

Comment: Is there an easier way than getting into registry files? That seems a bit extensive for what seems like a common problem.